# Как вызвать событие кликом по столбцу (BarChart) в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

Хочу вывести в консоль индекс стобца при нажатии мыши. Для примера скидываю свою реализацию

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import random

class MainWidow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800 ,500)
        series = self.append_series()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(series)
        self.chart.setTitle("Simple percentbarchart example")

        chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

    def append_series(self):
        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set1 = QBarSet("Mid")
        set2 = QBarSet("Max")

        set0.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])
        set1.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])
        set2.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])

        series = QStackedBarSeries()

        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.setBarWidth(1)

        return series

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = MainWidow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [QStackedBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedbarseries.html) есть сигнал [clicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbarseries.html#clicked), что вернет индекс столбца и по какой части попали при клике.

Добавьте строку `series.clicked.connect(self._on_click_series)` и метод:

```
def _on_click_series(self, index, bar_set):
    print(index, bar_set)
```

Пример:

```
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
import random

class MainWidow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(800 ,500)
        series = self.append_series()
        self.chart = QChart()
        self.chart.addSeries(series)
        self.chart.setTitle("Simple percentbarchart example")

        chartView = QChartView(self.chart)
        chartView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)

    def append_series(self):
        set0 = QBarSet("Min")
        set1 = QBarSet("Mid")
        set2 = QBarSet("Max")

        set0.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])
        set1.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])
        set2.append([random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(5)])

        series = QStackedBarSeries()
        series.clicked.connect(self._on_click_series)

        series.append(set0)
        series.append(set1)
        series.append(set2)
        series.setBarWidth(1)

        return series

    def _on_click_series(self, index, bar_set):
        print(index, bar_set.label())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window  = MainWidow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: и добавить нечего кроме `+` :), хотя `print(index, bar_set.label())`  будет красивше :)

Comment: @S.Nick, подправил :)